# How To Send an E-mail to an Employee Whose email id is in another object.

Tags: community, visual-workflow

I have created an object with name Customer Details in which i have also stored email id of customers... I have another object with name Billings. 
I used customer ID from Customer Details as lookup in Billings for billing Details of customer.. i want to send to an email with all these bill details to Email Id of that particular Customer.. How can i do this ?

Comment: You need to create a email template for Billing details. Are you sending emails manually from Customer Details screen and you are sending emails upon triggering an action?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one idea is to use the standard Contact object to store customer details rather than using your custom object. Create a Contact for each customer, and have a lookup relationship from Billing to Contact. Then if you are sending email via workflow/process builder upon a certain event (this is my assumption, but please provide additional information about the context if that is wrong) you can choose to send to a Related Contact when you configure the action.

If you want to stick with the custom object:

- Create an email template and merge in the necessary fields from Billing
- Create a hidden field on Billing, Customer_Email__c
- Create a workflow rule on Billing and specify the appropriate criteria that should send an email (e.g. you mark the Billing as "Finalized")
- Create a workflow action that sets the value of Customer_Email__c equal to Customer_Details__r.Email__c (or whatever the name is)
- Create a workflow email alert and choose "Email Field" as the person to whom it should be sent; select your hidden field

Comment: N.B. `Billing.Customer_Email__c` has to be of type `Email`. I've done this approach myself and then the business asks to support comma-separated email addresses :-(

Comment: I tried this..But problem is that i am unable to fetch email from CustomerDetails object in email field of Billing object. I want to fetch this by using customerId field which is used as lookup field in Billing object

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you have to create email template. Here to show the billing details (if there are multiple billing records) in the template you need to create Visualforce email template.

If you are sending emails from Customer Details screen via "Send Email" button you can select the customer email id.

In case you are sending emails based on certain action then you can leverage Process Builder for sending emails.

Comment: i want to send email via "send email " button when working on a visualforce page on Billing object & I want that when i fill cust-id in form.. then email should be  send to email ID of that cust-id.